# S3 bucket does not update the change from gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I have created one simple react for practicing gitlab's CI/CD pipeline. I successfully implement the CI/CD pipeline and deployed it in the S3 bucket. When I edit the app and push to the gitlab, my pipeline works fine and deployed to the S3 bucket. But in my browser it does not display the updated app. It shows the first version. Seems like production build does not work.

**This is my gitlab's `.gitlab-ci.yml` setup**

```
image: 'node:12'
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn run test

variables:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  AWS_REGION: $AWS_REGION
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: $S3_BUCKET_NAME

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build


deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  image: python:latest
  script:
     - pip install awscli
     - aws s3 cp build/ s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/ --recursive --include "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to explicitly assign a value to the AWS KEY_ID, ACCESS_KEY, REGION variables. They are used by default.
2. You do not need to use the --include "*" parameter, by default it will.

I think the problem is not with the pipeline. Possibly in browser cache, possibly in bucket settings on AWS

Comment: Did not help mate :( .

Comment: when I delete the build folders then run `npm run build` then deploy to the gitlab, Then I can see the changes. Is it the right way to deploy?